# Can you install Google Protocol Buffers on Heroku?

Tags: heroku, protocol-buffers

**Context**

I'm new to Heroku, and fairly new to Google Protocol Buffers.

**Steps Taken**

- Searched Stack Overflow
- Searched Heroku help
- Searched Google

**Question**

Is there way to install the Google Protocol Buffers on the Heroku platform?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. Protobufs involve generated code and a support library typically shipped with the binary that's using it.

What are you ultimately trying to do?

Comment: Run a python script that consumes a protobuf feed, have this python script running on heroku inside the flask framework.

Comment: Just include the Python Protobuf code along with your program, like any other library.  You don't need to install anything.

Comment: @KentonVarda thanks! Can you add this as an answer and I'll upvote you. Also primary author of buffers, wow.

Comment: @KentonVarda so the thing I must be thinking of that needs to be installed is the compiler? This is something you'd install on you desktop to generate the relevant libraries from a .proto file?

Comment: @drc - Done.  (Sorry for the dalay.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to "install" Protobufs to use it at run-time.  Just bundle the Protobuf Python code and the code generated by the Protobuf compiler together with your application's other code.  The compiler (`protoc`) is only needed to generate code; it is not used when your application actually runs.  So, there should be no problem.

If you want to use the experimental C-extension-backed implementation (which is off by default), you will also need to include the `.so` file implementing the extension.  I am not personally very familiar with C extensions so I'm not sure exactly where you're supposed to put it, but again, you should be able to bundle it with your application without installing anything.  I am also not very familiar with Heroku so I do not know if they will let you run C extensions -- I know that AppEngine, in comparison, does *not* allow extensions.